# What's wrong with this htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to move a site from a set of static html pages on one domain, to a new domain on WordPress. So I want each old page redirect to the corresponding new page on the new domain.

The structure on old domain is like so:

```
http://www.example.com/page.html
```

and the new domain has this structure:

```
http://www.example-new.com/category/sub-category/page/
```

So I tried this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.domain-old\.com/page1.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-new.com/new-category/new-sub-category/page1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.domain-old\.com/page2.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-new.com/new-category/new-sub-category/page2/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.domain-old\.com/page3.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-new.com/new-category/new-sub-category/page3/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.domain-old\.com/page4.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-new.com/new-category/new-sub-category/page4/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.domain-old\.com/page5.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-new.com/new-category/new-sub-category/page5/ [R=301,L]
```

And it works (kinda). The only GIANT problem is that now all pages redirect to the first new page, in this case `http://www.domain-new.com/new-category/new-sub-category/page1/`

Obviously I'm not an expert, but I spent hours on Google looking for an answer and trying things and can't figure how to do this, the closest I have found is about redirecting `domain A` to `domain b` removing the extension, so this is my last resource.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This condition is the main problem:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://www.domain-old\.com/page1.html [NC]
```

This will always **evaluate to `true`** because variable `HTTP_HOST` only matches **host name** part of a web request not the complete URL.

You can use this single rule in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain-old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)\.html$ http://www.domain-new.com/new-category/new-sub-category/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: You need 15+ reps to upvote any answer. Now you have 17 so you can upvote if you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are over-complicating this. Instead of all that processing, just use the Redirect Directive.

```
Redirect 301 /page1.html /new-category/new-sub-category/page1/
Redirect 301 /page2.html /new-category/new-sub-category/page2/
Redirect 301 /page3.html /new-category/new-sub-category/page3/
Redirect 301 /page4.html /new-category/new-sub-category/page4/
```